# Update multiple items in Room, how?

Tags: android, android-room, android-database

I would like to update a list of items, but it only updates 1 item, and if there are more than 1 item in the list, the app exits immediately without any error message.

```
fun onUpdateItem(list: ArrayList<Item>?) = viewModelScope.launch {
        list?.forEach {
            val item = it.copy(updated = 1, updatedTime =  System.currentTimeMillis())
            ItemDao.update(item)
        }

        itemEventChannel.send(ItemEvent.RefreshAdapter())
    }
```

DAO:

```
@Update
suspend fun update(item: Item)
```

Comment: `the app exits immediately without any error message.` i doubt this, are you sure you're correctly checking for a stack trace ?

Comment: The first update succeed, but after logcat shows in verbose mode: I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5093 SIG: 9
run tab also

Comment: @a_local_nobody I use debug tool, but after the first item I see only, that the CoroutineDispatcher starts to invoke, and the 2nd list iteration doesn't continue...

Comment: Maybe I should use SQLite for updating more items... But it is interesting why can't I update more items